# D3DXMatrixTransformation2D acting weird

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, directx, sprite

I want to rotate my 2D sprites at their position and not any other point, but I have trouble with the function.

I saw people using D3DXMatrixTransformation2D in this way (scaling excluded):

```
D3DXMATRIX mat;

D3DXVECTOR2 center(sprite.width / 2, sprite.height / 2);

D3DXVECTOR2 pos(sprite.x, sprite.y)

D3DXMatrixTransformation2D(
            &mat,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &center,
            sprite.rotation,
            &pos);
```

But doing this my sprites rotate in a laaaaarge circle around some strange point.

I tried and tried and come up with this solution, but it feels like it has some side-effects while I further manipulate entity coordinates and stuff.

```
D3DXVECTOR2 pos(sprite.x + (sprite.width / 2), sprite.y + (sprite.height / 2))

D3DXMatrixTransformation2D(
            &mat,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &pos,
            sprite.rotation,
            NULL);
```

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: It makes sense to me that the first approach would cause it to rotate in a large circle.  However, what problems are you seeing with the second approach?

Comment: None. I found out that the side-effects were coming from something else.
Still a bit strange that I only found the first approach while I was sure people wanted mine^^

Answer (score 0):

One little catch that can leave you scratching your head for a while, is if your image file has dimensions larger than the part of the image you're trying to rotate.
What I mean is, if your image file is in something like 512x512, and you have a small cat in the bottom left which is only 64x64, and the rest of it is at 0 alpha, it will take the centre of the image file, not of the cat.

If this is what's happening to you, you can either move the cat, or whatever image it is, to the centre of the image file, or have a look a bit further in DirectX where you can define a rectangle and use that as a cut-out from the image file to bound your image (cat).